# Bitbucket pipeline reuse source code from previous step

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Basically, I don't want pipeline step clone code on next steps, only first step will clone the source code a time. Another reason is if step clone the source code (and doesn't use the source code from previous) the built code will be lost.

I known that the bitbucket pipeline has the artifacts feature but seems it only store some parts of the source code.

The flow is:

Step 1: Clone source code.
Step 2: Run in parallel two steps, one install node modules at root folder, one install node module and build js, css at app folder.
Step 3: Will deploy the built source code from step 2.

Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: node:11.15.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and Test
        script:
          - echo "Cloning..."
        artifacts:
          - ./**
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Install build
          clone:
            enabled: false
          caches:
            - build
          script:
            - npm install
      - step:
          name: Install app
          clone:
            enabled: false
          caches:
            - app
          script:
            - cd app
            - npm install
            - npm run lint
            - npm run build
    - step:
        name: Deploy
        clone:
          enabled: false
        caches:
          - build
        script:
          - node ./bin/deploy

definitions:
  caches:
    app: ./app/node_modules
    build: ./node_modules
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After research hundred pages but cannot find anything, then I must try one by one by myself, finally I found the pattern for the artifacts of all the files:

```
artifacts:
  - '**'
```